# why a blank html return

Tags: javascript, html

I got this template from this [site](http://cssscript.com): After trying out some templates, they were ok. But trying out this bot template am getting a blank html return on this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BotUI - Hello World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/botui/build/botui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/botui/build/botui-theme-default.css" />
    <meta name="description" content="A hello world bot. A conversational UI built using BotUI.">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="botui-app-container" id="hello-world">
      <bot-ui></bot-ui>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botui/build/botui.js"></script>
    <script>
    var botui = new BotUI('hello-world');

    botui.message.add({
      content: 'Hello World from bot!'
    });

    botui.message.add({
      human: true,
      content: 'Hello World from human!'
    });

    document.getElementById("hello-world").innerHTML = content;
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What could be the issue?
Regards

Comment: Simply because the var `content` is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template is working fine, the only issue here is that you need to remove following line

```
document.getElementById("hello-world").innerHTML = content;
```

I am not sure, why you have added this line. All the messages should be rendered via `botui.message.add()` method. `BotUI` will handle content insertion.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BotUI - Hello World</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/botui/build/botui.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/botui/build/botui-theme-default.css" />
    <meta name="description" content="A hello world bot. A conversational UI built using BotUI.">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="botui-app-container" id="hello-world">
      <bot-ui></bot-ui>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/latest/vue.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botui/build/botui.js"></script>
    <script>
    var botui = new BotUI('hello-world');

    botui.message.add({
      content: 'Hello World from bot!'
    });

    botui.message.add({
      human: true,
      content: 'Hello World from human!'
    });

    // document.getElementById("hello-world").innerHTML = content;
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```